# Liferay: Allow remote access to JSON Web Services

Tags: javascript, cors, liferay

I'm trying access to from the same machine but in a different port to the JSON Web Services provided by Liferay.

I have the following properties set in the `portal-ext.properties` file:

```
json.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1
auth.token.check.enabled=true
jsonws.servlet.https.required=false
json.web.service.enabled=true
axis.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1
json.service.auth.token.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1
```

I have also configured the `web.xml` file from `$LIFERAY_HOME/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` and added the following although in some posts in the forum said that it wasn't necessary:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I can access with curl to the endpoint but I can't from the application running in the other port, where I get the following error:

```
 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The piece of code that does the request in Javascript is the following:

```js
var url = `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-email-address/?companyId=20116&emailAddress=test%liferay.com&p_auth=${key}`;

var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Basic Y2FsYmVyY2FAYXV0ZW50aWEuY29tOnRlc3Q=');
xhr.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');

xhr.send(data);
```

I think it has to do with the `portal-ext.properties` configuration, perhaps with the port. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I decided to follow was to create an [OSGi module](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/osgi-basics-for-liferay-development) using the [blade cli](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/blade-cli) provided by Liferay to scaffold a rest service ([blade.rest](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-gradle/blade.rest)) with Jax-RS (As explained [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/jax-ws-and-jax-rs)). From there I configured the CXF Endpoint and the REST Extender. Then I modified the `UsersRestService` class to the following:

```
package com.liferay.blade.samples.rest;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalService;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

@ApplicationPath("/blade.users")
@Component(
    immediate = true, property = {"jaxrs.application=true"},
    service = Application.class
)
public class UsersRestService extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return Collections.singleton(this);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUsers() {
        String json = "{\n" + "  \"value\": \"cool\"\n" + "}";
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .entity(json)
                .build();
    }

    @Reference
    private volatile UserLocalService _userLocalService;

}
```

In this class you have access to Liferay's services so you can expose what you want to your API Rest.

The last thing I have to check is the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" property, as it seems somewhere it's assigned but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2):

This is not realy a Liferay misconfiguration but rather a browser security related issue known as CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) but in general it boils down to the fact that in order for `site A` to load a resource from `site B` (which is essentially what `XMLHttpRequest` does), `site B` need to specify that the resource is available to `site A` via special header!

Liferay obviously does not do that as it has no way of knowing where you will consume resources from. For what you are trying to do to work you need to create and deploy to Liferay a servlet filter where you add the appropriate headers yourself. An example of such filter is available [here](https://github.com/topolik/presentations/blob/master/jsonws-services-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/devlife/CORSFilter.java).

Comment: Thank you! That clears some things up! Although I'm wondering if there is any way to whitelist domains from the `portal-ext.properties` file.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of